# Failure to automatically start an add-on in SAP Business One

Tags: runtime-error, sapb1

When configuring for the Add-on to start automatically, I get the following error.
It should be noted that, when started manually, it opens without problems.

Image showing the error obtained

[image]

Comment: Try running B1 as admin. Sometimes it's an install issue. Barring that, uninstall and reinstall the add-on, or contact the add-on provider to see if they have a solution.

Comment: We are the complement providers.
We have already tried the solutions described, thank you very much for your response.

Comment: When running manually is it connecting using the development connection string? Is it a problem of not picking up the connection string command line argument?

Comment: Thank you very much @Daz, your comment was the solution. The problem was in the connection chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the connection string.